How can I sort dates to nearest date in Swift
I started studying programming languages ​​quite recently
The essence of the problem is this - in SwiftData I created a model with the property of the date of birth and by picker I want to sort from the oldest, from the youngest and by the date closest to today
private extension [Person] {
    
    func sort(on option: SortingOption) -> [Person] {
        
        switch option {
            
        case .older:
            self.sorted { $0.birthday < $1.birthday }
        case .younger:
            self.sorted { $0.birthday > $1.birthday }
        case .closeToNow:
            self.sorted { person1, person2 in
                let calendar = Calendar.current
                let day = calendar.component(.day, from: person1.birthday)
                let month = calendar.component(.month, from: person1.birthday)
                
                let day2 = calendar.component(.day, from: Date.now)
                let month2 = calendar.component(.month, from: Date.now)
                
                return day < day2 || month < month2
            }
        }
    }
}

I don't understand how to sort the date so that the closest ones by day and month are shown first

You don't need a calendar for this. You can use the .distance(to:) function to get the distance to a date. After getting it, get the absolute value and compare it.
case .closeToNow:
    self.sorted { person1, person2 in
        let person1Diff = person1.birthday.distance(to: .now)
        let person2Diff = person2.birthday.distance(to: .now)

        return abs(person1Diff) < abs(person2Diff)
    }

And here's the shorthand for it:
case .closeToNow:
    self.sorted { abs($0.birthday.distance(to: .now)) < abs($1.birthday.distance(to: .now)) }

If the version doesn't support .now, you can use .init() instead.

This was my first idea but it assumes the time part of all the dates are the same since the smallest relevant value is day.

Actually this won’t work even if the time is the same since it will still depend on what value now is. Example, one person had their birthday yesterday and one has it tomorrow, depending on when during the day the sorting is done we will get a different result even though they are both 1 day away.

The problem with your solution is that you are getting the absolute month and day values from the dates rather than the distance between dates, in this case the distance between each person’s birthdate and the current date.
We can get the difference in days by using dateComponents(:from:to:), for example
let days1 = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: .now, to: person1.birthday).day!

The full code would then be
case .closeToNow:
    self.sorted { person1, person2 in
        let days1 = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: .now, to: person1.birthday).day!
        let days2 = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: .now, to: person2.birthday).day!

         return abs(days1) < abs(days2)
     }     


You can extend the Array type to provide a method that sorts Person objects based on different SortingOption cases, such as sorting by age (older or younger) or sorting by how close a person's birthday is to the current date (closeToNow).
private extension Array where Element == Person {
    
    // Sort the array based on a provided sorting option
    func sort(on option: SortingOption) -> [Person] {
        
        switch option {
            
        case .older:
            // From oldest to youngest
            return self.sorted { $0.birthday < $1.birthday }
            
        case .younger:
            // From youngest to oldest
            return self.sorted { $0.birthday > $1.birthday }
            
        case .closeToNow:
            // Sort by proximity of birthday to the current date
            return self.sorted { person1, person2 in
                let calendar = Calendar.current
                let currentDate = Date.now
                
                // Get the day and month components of both persons' birthdays
                let components1 = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: person1.birthday)
                let components2 = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: person2.birthday)
                
                // Get the current date components
                let currentComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: currentDate)
                
                // Calculate the number of days between the current date and each person's birthday
                let daysSince1 = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: currentComponents, to: components1).day ?? 0
                let daysSince2 = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: currentComponents, to: components2).day ?? 0
                
                // Sort by the absolute difference in days to the current date
                return abs(daysSince1) < abs(daysSince2)
            }
        }
    }
}

Usage Example:
let sortedByAge = people.sort(on: .older)
let sortedByProximity = people.sort(on: .closeToNow)

This method is flexible, allowing you to sort the array based on different criteria easily.
